# Where is Python's String Interpolation Operator defined formally?

Tags: python, string, string-interpolation

I am working on an article on Python string formatting and I am curious where are the workings of the % operator defined formally. I could not find a PEP defining the operator, I only found references in the official documentation.

For Python 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations
For Python 3.6: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Does anyone know where I can find them?

Comment: Do you mean in the source code, or in the documentation?

Comment: I believe %-formatting predates PEPs.  Either way, what more formal definition could there be than the official documentation?

Comment: That *is* the definition. In general, note that Python's behaviour is defined by the CPython reference implementation.

Comment: In the documentation.
I know it works by using the BINARY_MODULO opcode and having special treatment in the source code

Comment: Why do you think the pages you linked to aren't the documentation you want? It's no different from the `+` operator having a different meaning depending on whether it's being used with numbers or strings.

Comment: @jwodder A more formal definition perhaps. I see the documentation as the guide for using a feature, not the definition of it.
PEP's for example define the reasons for a feature, how should it work and how should it not.

Comment: @Mickey695: There's not going to be any more formal documentation for %-formatting besides the source code itself.  Python's not something like Haskell or Scheme with tens of pages of mathematically-defined formal semantics.  What do you even need that the documentation lacks?

Comment: @jwodder I was hoping to put a reference in my article to the exact definition of it. Like there is PEP 3101 for str.format and PEP 498 for f-string


.However since it appears there exists no such thing I guess the documentation will suffice

Comment: Just like jonsharpe said, the documentation is the exact definition. [PEPs propose and discuss new features](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/#what-is-a-pep). Giving a technical definition of the proposed featured is a part of it, but that doesn't make it superior to the documentation. I could understand citing a PEP if you wanted to cite the rationale behind an added feature, but for a technical definition, use the documentation.

Comment: @Mickey695: PEP1 was added on 13-Jun-2000.  Anything before this date won't have a PEP.  I found a user created quick reference on comp.lang.python from 3-Oct-1994 that refers to "Format operator for strings (%). Uses sprintf codes. Supports: %, c, s, i, d, u, o, x, X, e, E, f, g, G."  So if string interpolation is on a quick reference in 1994 you can be sure that it's older than that.  Guido van Rossum released Python 0.9.0 in February 1991.  I wouldn't be suprised if string formatting was included from the very beginning.  Python is written in C and this feature copies C's `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Steven Rumbalski's answer I have decided to mark this question as answered.

Unfortunately it appears that there is no formal definition of the interpolation operator except for the documentation.